# Flutter : make splash screen load all api's data

Tags: flutter, api, async-await, splash-screen

I have flutter app need to load some api's data in splash screen which contain animation.

```
class _SplashPageState extends State<SplashPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      var auth = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false);
      auth.chekingAuthVariables();

      var loading = Provider.of<LoadingProvider>(context, listen: false);
      loading.getBrands();
      loading.getVideos();

      var catsProv = Provider.of<CatProviders>(context, listen: false);
      catsProv.getCategoryList();
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedSplashScreen(
      backgroundColor: ColorManager.tabBottonNonActive,
      duration: 3000,
      splash: 'assets/splash.png',
      nextScreen: const MainTabPage(),
      splashTransition: SplashTransition.slideTransition,
    );
  }
}
```

the duration of animation is 3 seconds, sometimes when the net is slow the api's data dont load which make a problem for loading some screens.
How can I make the duration of animation finish after loading all api's data?

Answer (score 0):

```
void loadAPIData() {
          WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
          var auth = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false);
          auth.chekingAuthVariables();
    
          var loading = Provider.of<LoadingProvider>(context, listen: false);
          loading.getBrands();
          loading.getVideos();
    
          var catsProv = Provider.of<CatProviders>(context, listen: false);
          catsProv.getCategoryList();
          // run the animation indefinitely and use navigate after retrieving all data
          Navigator.push(
          context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondRoute()),
             );
        });
    }
```

I noticed you are making API calls without using `await`, which is quite odd considering you are loading data from an asynchronous source.